# Can't figure out how the header authentication works when parsing Json

Tags: android, json, authentication, android-volley

I am trying to get some data from an online API via Json, but can't figure out how the authentication works as I have never done this before.
It is not a user-password pair, but based on a unique key.
The Curl looks like this:

> curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "authorization: Bearer [*unique key*]" 'url to Json Object'

Haven't tried much else as I am new to implementing json in java. The list does not load and am getting the following in logcat:

> E/Volley: [31231] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for URL

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private PlayerListAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<PlayerListItem> mPlayerList;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.playerList);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mPlayerList = new ArrayList<>();

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJson();
}

private void parseJson() {
    String url = getString(R.string.url_to_members);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("items");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject players = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String playerName = players.getString("name");
                            String playerRole = players.getString("role");
                            int playerTrophies = players.getInt("trophies");
                            int playerDonations = players.getInt("donations");

                            mPlayerList.add(new PlayerListItem(playerName, playerRole, playerTrophies, playerDonations));
                        }

                        mAdapter = new PlayerListAdapter(MainActivity.this, mPlayerList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String apiToken = "Bearer" + Base64.encodeToString(getString(R.string.api_key).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Accept:", "application/json");
            headers.put("authorization:", "Bearer " + apiToken);
            return headers;
        }
    };

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

Comment: remove `:` from each header's `key`

Comment: like try `Accept` instead of `Accept:`

Comment: and you already prepend `Bearer` in your `apiToken` variable no need to prepend it again while putting it into header

Comment: Still getting the same error. Tried just removing the colons and removing `Bearer` as well.

Comment: debug your code and retrieve these headers and try calling api on postman or some other api testing tool first

Comment: Did that. Seemed that the issue was to revers the order in which I put the headers. The last one has to be the first.

Comment: no it doesn't matter

Comment: well, it worked for me